# Finding hidden or system files containing ~ using Dir() in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to rename a series of files for SharePoint that contain illegal characters such as #, &, ~, etc.  I modified the code from [this](http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/recursive_folder_search.html) site to find the files/folders to rename. When I run the following command

```
strTemp = Dir(strFolder & "*~*", vbHidden)
```

(or with any other attributes for that matter) I get a huge list of files in the directory that do not contain a `~`, and yet it still does not seem to find some files that contain an initial `~` (such as temporary files caused by editing a document that were never deleted).

Anybody out there know how to locate those files?

Comment: Just a note, that "huge list of files" doesn't include ones that are 8 characters or shorter.  I assume this is a holdover from DOS filename length limitations.

Comment: Can you narrow what you're looking for down more than having a tilde anywhere in the file?   For example if the tilde is always at the beginning or end you can make a better wildcard pattern.

Comment: I think you're right--all long filenames have a secret short version that includes a tilde.

Comment: It seems to give me the same issue even when I use "~*" or "*~".  If I delete the initial ~ from the filename and then search for it using something else, it can find it using the System file search.  Otherwise, it will not list it.

Comment: Aha!  Figured it out.  Sorry, the ~ was a red herring.  The answer was to use a '6' as the option to search for vbHidden AND vbSystem.  From the documentation on the Dir function it wasn't clear to me how to combine attributes.

Comment: Please submit it as your own answer to avoid further efforts from community. You'll be able to accept it in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for posting this as an answer but I don't seem able to add a comment.

ecksc has answered his own question, but I just want to point out that you don't need to replace the constants with the number 6. To combine attributes you can add them using `+`, for example:

```
strTemp = Dir(strFolder & "*~*", vbHidden + vbSystem)
```